# Is there Python C API equivalent for `float.as_integer_ratio` method?

Tags: python, floating-point, python-c-api

In plain Python we can write something like

```py
>>> (0.5).as_integer_ratio()
(1, 2)
```

Is there a way to get this result through Python C API? The only thing I see is [an implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3e7ee02327db13e4337374597cdc4458ecb9e3ad/Objects/floatobject.c#L1532-L1601).

Comment: You can call any Python callable with the `PyObject_Call*` set of functions. I assume you know this and are looking for a more direct way to access it? (which I don't think there is)

Comment: @DavidW: thanks, that could work, but I was hoping that there is some sort of utility that does exactly that by mutating pointers instead of creating intermediate `tuple` object

Comment: Not built into Python I think. The implementation looks well-commented and fairly simple so if I were you I'd just copy and modify to get your desired inputs/outputs.